# Yii2 How to share cookie between in two sites

Tags: php, cookies, yii2

I have two sites like:

```
www.abc.com
test.abc.com
```

Each site enable cookie validation, and has diffirent cookie validation key. I want to set a cookie from test.abc.com, and use it from www.abc.com

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => '_name',
    'value' => '_value',
    'domain' => '.abc.com'
]));
```

As the cookie validation, www.abc.com can't get that cookie.
Is there any way I can get it?

Comment: Here is my ugly solution. I wrote a function to get the cookie value according by the method 'Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validateData'. Avoid the camparing action, return the array directly.

Comment: There is a documentation page for this now: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/yii2/2945/cookies/9999/cross-subdomain-authentication-and-identity-cookies#t=201701040158405174266